# How To Remove Display Rule From a Ribbon Command in CRM Online?

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a command for a button defined as follows:

```xml
<CommandDefinition Id="new.lead.CreditCheck.Command">
    <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="new.lead.CreditCheck.EnableRule" />
    </EnableRules>
    <DisplayRules>
        <DisplayRule Id="new.lead.CreditCheck.DisplayRule" />
    </DisplayRules>
    <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="new.LeadDynamic.creditCheck" Library="$webresource:new_Lead_dyn.js" />
    </Actions>
</CommandDefinition>
```

If I go and remove the Display Rule from the command, (but keep the actual Display Rule definition) it looks like this:

```xml
<CommandDefinition Id="new.lead.CreditCheck.Command">
    <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="new.lead.CreditCheck.EnableRule" />
    </EnableRules>
    <DisplayRules />
    <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="new.LeadDynamic.creditCheck" Library="$webresource:new_Lead_dyn.js" />
    </Actions>
</CommandDefinition>
```

I get an error when attempting to import (attempted to use the Ribbon Workbench and got the same error as well)

> The ribbon item 'new.lead.CreditCheck.Command' is dependent on
>   .

I'm attempting to remove the dependency, but apparently I can't remove it since it exists!  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you remove the `DisplayRule` itself from the `RulesDefinitions->DisplayRules` node too? That's my first guess, that you need to remove the reference from the `CommandDefinition` and import it. Then you could remove it from `RulesDefinitions` and import that. It would be odd, but as you know, `RibbonXml` is often funky.

Comment: I agree @Nicknow, the RibbonXml is really funky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this a bug in CRM, but in order to perform this operation, you have to delete the command, and then **publish the solution!**  Once the command is deleted, you can delete the Display Rule.  You can't do this in one step!

If your command is especially complicated, you can export the solution, delete the command, import the solution, remove the Display Rule and add back the command without the display rule and import.

Comment: I would consider it a bug too. I can see how it works the same as any dependency in Dynamics CRM, but given the way RibbonXml works (i.e., allowing deletes via a solution import) it really should handle this situation. Probably needs to be posted on Microsoft Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has a `CommandDefinition` which depends on a `DisplayRule` with the ID "new.lead.CreditCheck.DisplayRule". You cannot remove the `DisplayRule` from the RibbonDiffXml as long there is a published and/or unpublished component depending on it, in this case the `CommandDefinition`.

Therefore you need to remove all references to the `DisplayRule` first and then publish these customizations. Having this done, you should be able to remove the `DisplayRule` itself.

The same procedure must be followed when you need to remove an obsolete attribute from an entity:

1. Remove the attribute from all forms, views etc.
2. Publish customizations
3. Remove the attribute from the entity model
4. Publish customizations

In this respect the behaviour of Dynamics CRM is i.m.o. 'by design'.

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you've described.  Let me change the wording slightly because it is a little misleading

Comment: Does that edit make more sense.  The only change I made to the Ribbon XML is the change I show.

Comment: Could it be the Ribbon Workbench removes obsolete rules when publishing the ribbon? Often I work with the customizations.xml itself and have not seen this type of behaviour before.

Comment: I thought that as well, so I manually made the changes and the got the same error.  The Ribbon Workbench is at the mercy of CRM...